# Wildcard in JsonPath

Tags: java, json, groovy, rest-assured, jsonpath

I am parsing a JSON like below:

```json
jobs1: [
{
  request: {
    body: {
      jobID: "79ceeeff-53b9-4645-80bd-95dfca6fe1e9",
...
jobs2: [
{
  request: {
    body: {
      jobID: "60e7c286-f936-4f96-87bc-6bd55f107514",
```

And looking for a way to use wildcards in the JSON path.

I am using the [RestAssured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured) framework in Java. After executing the code like below:

```
List<String> ids = get("/state/").path("*.request.body.jobID");
System.out.println(ids);
```

I expect to get:

```
[79ceeeff-53b9-4645-80bd-95dfca6fe1e9, 60e7c286-f936-4f96-87bc-6bd55f107514]
```

But instead I get an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON expression:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: *. @ line 1, column 27.
                        *.request.body.jobID
                         ^
```

I have looked through these tutorials, but nothing seemed to work for me:

https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath

How do I correctly use the wildcards in JsonPath?

Comment: Have you tried with `children` instead of the `*`?
Cf. https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/GettingStarted#jsonpath and http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath

Comment: @D.Kovács `"children().request.body.jobID"` gives `IllegalArgumentException: No signature of method: java.util.HashMap.children() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out how to use wildcards. But if you need a temp solution, the below works. def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
def jsonResponse = jsonSlurper.parseText(sampleJson);
def listOfJobIds = [];
jsonResponse.keySet().each{node -> 
 listOfJobIds.add(jsonResponse[node].request.body.jobID[0]);
}
log.info listOfJobIds;

Answer (score 5):

GOTO http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

And give input like green box in the given image.

Your pattern should be like below

> *.[*].request.body.jobID

Your JSON should be like below

```html
{
 jobs1: [{
   request: {
    body: {
     jobID: "79ceeeff-53b9-4645-80bd-95dfca6fe1e9"
    }
   }
  }
 ],
 jobs2: [{
   request: {
    body: {
     jobID: "60e7c286-f936-4f96-87bc-6bd55f107514"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Your will get result like below

```html
[
   "79ceeeff-53b9-4645-80bd-95dfca6fe1e9",
   "60e7c286-f936-4f96-87bc-6bd55f107514"
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`*.[*].request.body.jobID` this will extract the jobID's alone like below

```
[  
   "79ceeeff-53b9-4645-80bd-95dfca6fe1e9",
   "60e7c286-f936-4f96-87bc-6bd55f107514"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need `wildcards` here? This seems to be able to retrieve what you expect:

```
..request.body.jobID
```

Or even simpler:

```
..jobID
```